# How to disable initial view of PDF bookmarks panel?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, acrobat

The `hyperref` package automatically creates a list of PDF bookmarks, and it configures the PDF to have the initial view display the bookmarks panel, at least in <strike>Foxit Reader and</strike> Acrobat. To see the relevant setting in Acrobat, see *File > Properties > Initial View > Navigation Tab > `Bookmarks Panel and Page`*.

[image]

How can I (temporarily) turn off the intial Bookmarks Panel display upon compilation? 
I want it to be the `Page Only` setting.

*Note*: I know I can change the setting using Acrobat (Professional) once the PDF is created, but I want to control the setting upon compilation. The underlying driver for me is that when I view my PDF (after making changes in LaTeX, and compiling it), the bookmark panel makes the actual page shrink, making it too small to be readable.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me when I compile a document using `hyperref` without any options and viewing it in Adobe Reader 9.4.6 on Ubuntu; it always shows the page view on opening. Could you post a short example `.tex` source  that yields the described behaviour for you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `hyperref` option to set is `pdfpagemode`:

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone}
```

However this is not guaranteed to work with all PDF viewers; it should with Adobe Reader and Acrobat.

The key `pdfpagemode` can receive other values; from the `hyperref` documentation:

> Determines how the ﬁle is opening in Acrobat; the possibilities are `UseNone`, `UseThumbs` (show thumbnails), `UseOutlines` (show bookmarks), `FullScreen`, `UseOC` (PDF 1.5), and `UseAttachments` (PDF 1.6). If no mode is explicitly chosen, but the `bookmarks` option is set, `UseOutlines` is used.

Comment: FYIO: apparently, Foxit Reader 5.1 seems to remember per document  whether or not to show the bookmarks panel (based on whether you opened or closed the panel last time), irrespective of the hyperref setting.