# Hiding Bookmarks in PDFLaTeX

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable initial view of PDF bookmarks panel?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50814/how-to-disable-initial-view-of-pdf-bookmarks-panel)

I would like to hide bookmarks in my pdf which are appearing at left side of the PDF like chapters. I'm using `\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}` but I'm unable to hide the bookmarks. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Hi user1450092. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.